# Centering shapefile in layout view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, layouts

This is what my screen looks like now.

[image]

The yellow outline of the US is a shapefile and so are the blue dots. I am using one of the default basemaps in the background. I want center the map so that the entire US is visible. I've tried changing the scale but it hasn't fixed the issue. I can't simply drag the map because then it will be off the page I want to print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Table of Contents (the list of layers usually found on the left side of your ArcMap window), right-click on your US border shapefile and click "Zoom to Layer". That will zoom to the extents of the layer and center your view on the layer.

FYI, you can also zoom to one (or several) features in the layer, instead of the entire layer. To do that, open the layer's attribute table, select the feature(s) you're interested in, then right-click on the gray box to the left of one of the rows and click Zoom to Selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove Hawaii and Alaska from my shapefile to make it zoom correctly but all is good now. The quick response is much appreciated!

Comment: @Dillon You don't need to delete anything from your layer, see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you center your map in data view, layout view should show the same extent.

Answer (score 0):

In layout mode, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then use left-click to zoom in or out (left-click-hold + drag cursor) or right-click to pan (right-click-hold + drag cursor).

It's a long reach for the fingers, but is really nice for layout adjustments.